# IE8 / IE9 / IE11: text type input onkeyup: on keycode 13 loses focus

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

the following code should display the charcode of keys pressed including enter (13) but it doesn't in IE. In IE8 / IE9 / IE11 (and probably IE10 but I don't have it somewhere right now) it moves focus to another element when I press the enter key. Why and how to solve this ? I could use onkeydown, but why doesn't work with onkeyup as well as in all other browsers?

I should say that this will not happen if I remove the button element or the input type image but obviously a page will have many such elements.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function onuserinput(e) {
                var keyC = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.charCode;
                alert(keyC);
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="text" id="myinput" onkeyup="onuserinput(event);"/>
        <input type="image" id="img" src="" alt="random input type image" title=""/>
        <button id="aaa">random button</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Pretty sure it's too late to suppress the default behaviour of hitting the enter key in IE when the `onkeyup` event fires. You have to use `onkeydown` or `onkeypress` instead. Basically just IE being IE and not behaving in the same way as the other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Try **onkeyup**, it should work. As I understand **onuserinput** fires after pressing enter or losing focus, so keyup must fires before.

Comment: um I AM using onkeyup...there is no builtin function onuserinput it's what I call when onkeyup fires

Comment: Sorry, didn't read it well. Yes, you are using onkeyup. What I can say is that it must work on IE8, because I've done this on IE6/8 and works fine. Try to capture onkeyup for all the document, or only on input objects, and if event.target is your input - process it. Just an idea.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. IE default behavior, it seems, is submit the nearest button in the "form". For elude this behavior, include type="button" propierty to the html button, it works for me:

```
<button type='button'>This button will not submit by default</button>
```